# What is so special about Prime?

Tags: functions, number-theory, prime-numbers, big-numbers, system-limitations

When we try to evaluate `Prime` on big numbers (e.g. `10^13`) we encounter the following issue:

```
Prime[10^13]
```

> ```
> Prime::largp: Argument 10000000000000 in Prime[10000000000000] is too large 
> for this implementation. >>
>
> Prime[10000000000000]
> ```

Following this message, we can read in the documentation that the largest supported argument in `Prime` is typically about $2^{42}$. With  a kind of divide and conquer approach, we can figure out that the maximal argument of `Prime` is:

```
OmegaPrime = 7783516045221;
```

**1. What determines this number ? A hardware/software and/or conceptual/mathematical issue  or maybe an arbitrary  system cut-off ?**

The problem seems to be a bit more obscure, since one encounters something like this:

```
Prime @ {# + 1, #, # + 1} & @ OmegaPrime
```

> ```
> Prime::largp: Argument 7783516045222 in Prime[7783516045222] is too large for
> this implementation. >>
>
> { Prime[7783516045222], 249999997909357, 249999997909367}
> ```

(It takes more than two minutes to evaluate.)

An analog of `OmegaPrime` is `OmegaPrimePi` for `PrimePi` :

```
OmegaPrimePi = 25 10^13 -1;
```

I can find even bigger primes with `Prime` if I evaluate for example:

```
Select[Range[249999997909357, 25 10^13], PrimeQ] // Length
```

> ```
> 63142
> ```

```
Prime[ OmegaPrime + 63142]
```

> ```
> 250000000000043
> ```

However I cannot evaluate `PrimePi` for numbers greater than `OmegaPrimePi`. It appears that `Prime` has a dynamically extensible domain while `PrimePi`  does not.

**2. How do I detect this property in advance from the system ?**

I mean not to play around with e.g. `Select[Range[a,b], PrimeQ]`, but for example to read it from `Attributes` or anything else.

****UPGRADE version 12.1****

Domains of `Prime` as well as `PrimePi` have been significantly extended
and now

```
OmegaPrimePi = 2^63 - 1
```

> ```
>  9223372036854775807
> ```

It is a much larger domain than formerly:

```
OmegaPrimePi/(25 10^13 - 1) // N
```

> ```
> 36893.5
> ```

Now `OmegaPrime` is simply the value of `PrimePi` on `OmegaPrimePi`, namely

```
OmegaPrime = 216289611853439384;
```

and the domain of `Prime` is extensible as before, i.e. evaluating on the fresh kernel

```
Prime[OmegaPrime + 1]
```

> ```
>  Prime[216289611853439385]
> ```

```
Prime[OmegaPrime]
```

> ```
> 9223372036854775783
> ```

this took about $6$ minutes to evaluate on my computer.
`Prime[OmegaPrime]` is the gratest prime number below `OmegaPrimePi`.

```
Prime[OmegaPrime + 1]
```

> ```
> 9223372036854775837
> ```

Since *version 12.1* `PrimePi` works with several algorithms which can be chosen with `Method`.

Answers by Andrzej Kozłowski and Daniel Lichtblau were both helpful, although they haven't explained the origin of `OmegaPrime`.
Now with the last upgrade this issue becomes clear.

Comment: I love the questions people come up with. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for your support. I really have many questions but not too much time to formulate them.

Comment: Really a nice question. I doubt any answer (and I have none) will deserve more upvotes than the question.

Comment: @belisarius Thank You ! I believe there is a need for `Primes` tag since M contains quite a good functionality in this field and there could appear many interesting and related questions.

Comment: One should certainly not expect `Attributes` to answer such a question, as that function deals with various general-type properties. My guess is that the only possibility beyond experimentation is looking at the documentation. And if that doesn't help, ask Wolfram tech support.

Comment: @murray I gave `Attributes` here  only for instance of what one could expect since I had checked this before and it hadn't enlightened me more.

Comment: An interesting observation is that `Prime` calls `PrimePi` many (namely, 1,013,381) times when given an argument of your `OmegaPrime`: ``nums = Reap[Internal`InheritedBlock[{PrimePi}, Unprotect[PrimePi]; pp:PrimePi[n_] /; (Sow[n]; True) := pp; Protect[PrimePi]; Prime[7783516045221]]][[2, 1]]; ListLogLogPlot[nums, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000, Joined -> True]`` gives nearly a straight line. What this means, if anything, I have no idea, but it shows at least some concrete relationship between the two functions.

Comment: @OleksandrR. There is an obvious mathematical relationship between these functions : they are "almost" inverse, I mean e.g. : `Prime@PrimePi@Range[101, 105]` returns 'Range[101, 105]` , i.e. identity, but not `PrimePi@Prime`. There are also some issues of their internal implementations which are certainly more obscure.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually, I believe the issue reduced to that of implementing `PrimePi[]`. It is easy to implement `Prime[]` using `PrimePi[]` and `FindRoot[]` — in fact this is done on page 134 of [Bressoud and Wagon, "A Course in Computational Number Theory"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1930190107). So all you need is to have a fast implementation of `PrimePi[]`.

The first efficient way was found by Legendre in 1808. The modern approach of Lagarias, Miller and Odlyzko (1985)  gives `PrimePi[]` for $10^{20}$, which is larger than the *Mathematica* implementation. All this is discussed in detail in the Bressound and Wagon book. Curiously they include a [*Mathematica* package](http://www.macalester.edu/~bressoud/books.html) that implements the Lagarias, Miller and Odlyzko method, but it appears that (somewhat surprisingly) it has not been included in the *Mathematica* kernel.

---

> [J. C. Lagarias, V. S. Miller, and A. M. Odlyzko, *Computing* $\pi(x)$*: The Meissel-Lehmer method*, Math. Comp. 44 (1985), 537–560. MR 86h:11111](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1985-0777285-5)

Comment: However when I evaluate with a fresh kernel `PrimePi@249999999909367;// AbsoluteTiming//First` I get slightly bigger number than for `Prime@7783516045221;// AbsoluteTiming//First `

Comment: In my case Prime took slightly longer: 153.04 vs 151.9 for PrimePi. Prime certainly calls on PrimePi so all this means is that AbsoluteTiming is unreliable when the difference is so small.

Comment: Thank you for these interesting references. Apparently `Prime` and `PrimePi` are internally related. However it is not clear how `Prime` works when its arguments are greater than `OmegaPrime`. I suspect there is communication between `NextPrime` and/or `PrimeQ`, since these functions have domains upper-bounded only by `$MaxNumber`. Have you got any idea why `OmegaPrime` is just `7783516045221` ?

Answer (score 25):

It's due to an implementation-dependent issue. We should try to improve on it. Has not been much clamor to do so, therefore it has not been a high priority.

--- edit ---

I've had a look at the code. It is quite intentional that the largest is around what you state (I see the constant being set to $7.783516108362\times 10^{12}$). It has to do with this being `PrimePi[2.5*10^14]` or thereabouts, and that is due to (unknown to me) implementation limitations. Basically it's a case of "Thar be dragons". Some day maybe I'll get a chance to look into this morass. (Some day I'll no doubt wind up in the La Brea Tar Pits.)

--- end edit ---

Comment: I would love to hear from you more about those internal implementation issues. Have you got any idea why the value of `OmegaPrime` is `7783516045221` ? 
There seems to be no strict relation between implementation of Prime and `PrimePi`. Does `Prime` use `NextPrime` (or do they both use primality tests as in `PrimeQ`) when arguments exceed `OmegaPrime`?

Comment: I have run into this too and wondered why _Mathematica_ had this limit. A way to circumvent it would be some sort of mathlink/library link and C++ mixture.

Comment: @Artes See edited response. It's not much, but it's all I have to offer right now.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank You for the edit. The constant you've mentioned `OmegaPrime1` is such that `Prime[OmegaPrime1]= 249999999999977` is the largest prime smaller than `OmegaPrimePi`, so it is also such that `PrimePi[2.5*10^14]=OmegaPrime1`, however I have `OmegaPrime = 7783516045221` in `Mathematica` ver 7 as well as in ver. 8 (under `Windows`) so it is still a bit more puzzling why it is different.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have to emphasize that the domain of `Prime` is extensible during a session (I mentioned that in the post). I mean that `Prime[7783516108362]` returns the same with the fresh kernel. However after some playing around with e.g. `NextPrime` I can evaluate it getting what I wrote before in my comment.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I believe that there is a helpful comment by Oleksandr R. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime#comment9022_3327.  I suppose, that `Prime` works having defined in the system a kind of a sparse map of the values of `PrimePi`, and to evaluate `Prime` for an argument between any two consecutive values in that map it has to work in the same way as `NextPrime`. However I may be completely wrong with this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau oh! How much I do enjoy reading your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce this problem on my iMac and I did get somewhat a different result.

I entered

```
Prime[10^13]
```

and got

[image: output]

like you did.

I did make use of the offered assistance by Mathematica:

And got `ref/message/Prime/largp` for `Prime`, `PrimPi` and `ZetaZero`. This contained the message

The largest supported argument in `Prime` is typically about `2^42`.

So I entered

```
Prime[2^42]
```

and got

```
138666449011757
```

But some little check shows that the given limiting number is greater than the number with the error message. The upper limit given is about `4.39805` the number with the fail message of Your question posed. The example number in the largp message is `10^20` on my iMac.

I iterated the problem and found that the problem occurs between `7 10^12` and `8 10^12`. That confirms the answer of [@daniel-lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) roughly.

My results are:

- seems that Prime uses memoization. That hints toward recursive calculations.
- seems that fresh kernel is a meaningful hint for objective judgements.
- seems that this is due to performance choices hidden before the users.
- seems to be related with timing settings, but implicit as largp shows.
- this might change is Mathematica flags the computer it is installed on as capable for parallelization, or the type of parallel computing that is implemented in Mathematica.

To my astonishment on this question I got:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Prime[10^12*7]]
```

(* {9.*10^-6, 224066643897983} *)

Oh I am really fast!!!

Comment: Since when is 2^42 about 4.39805 times larger than 10^13??

Comment: The results are cached (so 9.*10^-6 is wrong) and calculated upwards if you do +1, also on my windows 11 with Intel it does not fail on 10^13. In fact, it prints 323780508946331. 10^14 also works. And 10^15. And even 10^16. Did not check further.

Comment: My statement `Prime` uses memoization is another wording for if run a second time, it is lightning-fast because is memorizes the numbers. This is for sure a property, an attribute of the local machine that hosts Mathematica.