# Interprocedural optimization

Tags: performance-tuning

Lets say I want to build a list of the first 1000000 primes. This is simple enough, I can just do:

`AbsoluteTiming[plist = Table[Prime[i], {i, 1000000}];]` and it takes 4.8 seconds.

I can also find out of the number of primes less than 15485863 (the million$^{th}$ prime) using :

`AbsoluteTiming[PrimePi[15485863]]` which takes negligible time.

My impression is that there is no way to get a precise `PrimePi[n]` result without actually finding all the primes less than `n`. This means that to create a list of the first 1000000 primes, it should take negligible time.

I believe though that instead of reusing the intermediaries generated from previous `Prime[n]` calls, it instead starts from scratch every time, and this is why it takes so long to run.

While I can write my own function to memoize this, I don't see how this could not be built in. Additionally, while in this case I can memoise the process, that is something that I cannot do in general.

I assume that in many cases involving table there would be significant savings from saving partial terms from the previous iterations, so I assume that there is a way to do this.

Is this a way to enable these optimizations, or is it just wishful thinking?

**Update:** Few things:
 - Regardless of how `Prime` or `PrimePi` is implemented, taking 4+ seconds to generate the first million primes is rather ridiculous (I have a simple little sieve in C# that can do just over 50 million primes in that time) and I think that it stands to reason that this is because it is doing the same work over and over an over again.

Perhaps this is a better example:
`AbsoluteTiming[list1 = Table[Sum[i,i,10000000+q],{q,1,10000}];]`
This took 95 seconds on my computer. That is more than a little excessive. The only possible way  that I can think of that it took that long was that for every iteration, it optimized it (hopefully just once, but less hopefully, every time) to $1/2 (1000000 + q) (1000001 + q)$ and then at every time evaluated it.

If I instead do `AbsoluteTiming[
 list1 = Table[1/2 (1000000 + q) (1000001 + q), {q, 1, 10000}];]` it takes just .06 seconds (much better). Is there a way to get it to always turn the first into the second? Additionally, I would tend to doubt that it realizes that the different in terms forms a linear equation and that it would be easier to do an two additions, than two divisions, three multiplications and a division.

Comment: It is possible to compute `PrimePi[n]` without enumerating all prime numbers less than $n$.  See for example Lehmer's recursive [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LehmersFormula.html).

Comment: Very useful to know.

Comment: I can't see the relation between the example in your update and the original question

Comment: I am asking about interprocedural optimization in general, not with the specific functions that I used in example one.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Primality Proving Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PrimalityProving/tutorial/PrimalityProving.html)?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `Prime` and `PrimePi` are not as you describe.

The [implementation notes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) say:

> Prime and PrimePi use sparse caching and sieving. For large *n*, the
>   Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko algorithm for PrimePi is used, based on
>   asymptotic estimates of the density of primes, and is inverted to give
>   Prime.

I don't know the details of this algorithm but you can get a sense of [how a prime-counting function works (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

Surely not all primes are calculated in order.

---

Regarding your update you seem to be asking more than one question.

`Prime` is not set up for rapid generation of sequential primes, but instead fairly rapid generation of arbitrarily indexed primes.

The second question seems to be about optimizing evaluation order.  I don't believe there is a *general* solution for automatic optimization, but in this case a well placed `Evaluate` works, causing the `Sum` to first be evaluated symbolically:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 list1 = Table[Evaluate[Sum[i, i, 10000000 + q]], {q, 1, 10000}];
]
```

> ```
> {0.0160009, Null}
> ```

Comment: My $n$ here is not large. And even if `Prime` uses a sieve, the sieve is not reused between different calls to `Prime`. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: @soandos What are you actually trying to do?  Is the call to `Prime` the bottleneck in your program?

Comment: @soandos I'm not sure what you are asking for but I think  this question, answers and comments could be useful : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime

Comment: @Artes and Mr. Wizard, see update