# How to find the domain and range of a function with Mathematica?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I'm studying calculus and in some exercises I am asked to find the domain and range of a function.  Does *Mathematica* have already a built-in function for this?

I can imagine some ways of doing so, but at the moment I want to know if there's a built-in function or some easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 22):

When this question was originally asked, the closest thing to a built in function was via the built-in `WolframAlpha` functionality.  As of V10, there's `FunctionDomain` and `FunctionRange`.

```
FunctionDomain[x + x/(x (x^2 - 1)), x]
(* Out: x < -1 || -1 < x < 1 || x > 1 *)

FunctionRange[x/(x (x^2 - 1)), x, y]
(* Out: y <= -1 || y > 0 *)
```

Both functions produce output that is *often* compatible with the groovy new `NumberLinePlot` function.

```
NumberLinePlot[%, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

**Original answer via WolframAlpha interface**

Here's how to access domain and range queries via WolframAlpha.

```
WolframAlpha["domain of x+x/(x(x^2-1))",
 {{"Result", 1}, "Output"}]
WolframAlpha["range of x/(x(x^2-1))",
 {{"Result", 1}, "Output"}]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[x < -1 || -1 < x < 0 || 0 < x < 1 || x > 1]
>
> HoldComplete[y < -1 || y > 0]
> ```

Answer (score 19):

If you have a domain, you can often find a range using [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html).

Examples:

```
In[1]:= Sin@Interval[{0, 2 Pi}]
Out[1]= Interval[{-1, 1}]

In[2]:= Sin@Interval[{0, Pi}]   
Out[2]= Interval[{0, 1}]
```

Comment: I'd love to see this answer expanded. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think there are so many additional comments on the same thing that there is not much I can expand on.  I was travelling again, so couldn't react earlier.

Answer (score 11):

[`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html) is a proper way for your task, but sometimes it is not the way to go. 
There are functions which can return neither their ranges nor domains, e.g. function yielding `k-th` non-trivial  zero of the `Riemman` zeta function. E.g. `ZetaZero[1000]//N` yields `0.5 + 1419.42 I`, while `N[ ZetaZero @ Interval[{1000, 10000}]]`
 yields `ZetaZero[Interval[{1000, 10000}]]`, however since it is weakly monotonic on the critical line with respect to the imaginary part (i.e. `0.5 + t I`, where t is a real number, )

```
N[ ZetaZero @ {1000, 10000}]
```

> ```
> {0.5 + 49.7738 I, 0.5 + 236.524 I}
> ```

It is known that ( purely mathematically speaking)  the domain of `ZetaZero` are integer numbers, but there are certain limitations of its implementation in `Mathematica`, e.g. there is no way to find its domain, only a kind of "divide and conquer" approach, e.g.

```
ZetaZero[10^7] // N

ZetaZero[10^7 + 1] // N
```

> ```
> 0.5 + 4.99238*10^6 I
>
> ZetaZero::largp: Argument 10000001 in ZetaZero[10000001] is too large for this 
>                    implementation. >>
> ZetaZero[10000001]
> ```

There is a second argument in `ZetaZero[k, t]` representing the k-th zero with imaginary part greater than t. Neither this works with `Interval`, though it is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) with respect to the second argument :

```
ZetaZero[105, Interval[{15., 35.5}]]
ZetaZero[105, {15., 35.5}]
```

> ```
> ZetaZero[105, Interval[{15., 35.5}]]
> {1/2 + 247.137 I, 1/2 + 253.07 I}
> ```

There are similar issues with e.g. `PrimePi` ( the `Mathematica` counterpart of the prime counting function $\pi(x)$) and `Prime`.

```
PrimePi[ Interval[{10, 100}]]
```

> ```
> PrimePi[ Interval[{10, 100}]]
> ```

but

```
PrimePi[{10, 100}]
```

> ```
> {4, 25}
> ```

```
Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 10, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

The maximal evaluatable argument for `PrimePi` is `25 10^13 -1`, while with `Prime` there is a bigger problem, like e.g. an apparently extensible domain :

```
Prime @ {# + 1, #, # + 1} & 7783516045221
```

> ```
> Prime::largp: Argument 7783516045222 in Prime[7783516045222] is too large for
> this implementation. >>
> {Prime[7783516045222], 249999997909357, 249999997909367}
> ```

You can find related details here :  [What is so special about Prime ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime).

There are infinitely many primes, however values of  $\pi(x)$ are known up to $x = 10^{23}$, look at e.g.  [Prime Counting Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html) on `MathWorld` .

Comment: Well, since these functions are expected to only take integer arguments, `Interval[]` is certainly not expected to interact nicely with them...

Comment: Well, `PrimePi` evaluates on real arguments, e.g. `PrimePi[1000. Pi]` yields `446`.

Comment: What do I need to know for understanding your answer? Your answer is amazing but I read it almost as if I were reading Japanese (I don't know japanese). Notice that this is not a critic, I just need references for understanding it.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira My intentions were 1.to explain certain limitations of using `Interval`. 2. to show limitations of built-in functions, especially with respect to their domains. 3. to demonstrate that sometimes representing of mathematical objects is far from high-fidelity.  There are `4` links where you can read more on these issues. I think that careful reading of the M documentation concerning the functions which I mentioned would be very helpful. If there are other doubts you should specify them more strictly. I hope I could help more and possibly edit and update my answer.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I think that `MathWorld` is an interesting repository of knowledge. If you have more detailed questions, try to ask them and I'll add a bit more extended clarifications.

Comment: @Artes Thanks.$ $

Answer (score 10):

Let me just add something about finding the domain:

You can often find the domain of a function `f[x]` using `Reduce`. Assuming the domain is a subset of the real numbers, the syntax would be

```
Reduce[Abs[f[x]] < Infinity, x, Reals]
```

Here are some examples:

**(1)**

A piecewise defined function:

```
Clear[f]; f[x_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {-1.5, x < 0},
   {3, x > 1},
   {Undefined, 0 < x < 1}
   }]

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image: piecewise]

```
Reduce[Abs[f[x]] < Infinity, x, Reals]

(* ==> x <= 0 || x >= 1 *)
```

This means x has to be less than `0` or larger than `1`.

**(2)**

A function with singularities:

```
Clear[f]; f[x_] := 1/Sin[x]

Plot[f[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: inverseSine]

```
Reduce[Abs[f[x]] < Infinity, x, Reals]

(*
==> 
C[1] \[Element] 
  Integers && (-Pi + 2 Pi C[1] < x < 2 Pi C[1] || 
   2 Pi C[1] < x < Pi + 2 Pi C[1])
*)

Last[%] /. C[1] -> n

(*
==> -Pi + 2 n Pi < x < 2 n Pi || 
 2 n Pi < x < Pi + 2 n Pi
*)
```

On the last line I've just made the conditions easier to read by introducing an integer `n` instead of the default constant `C[1]`.

Comment: Haha. You also solved another doubt I had: "How to make piecewise defined functions on Mathematica" I just didn't ask it because I could solve using a manual method but here it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, a set can be write in two(or more) form: one is `{3x | x in [0,1]}`, the other `{x | P(x)}`, where P is called a propositional function or predicate. Since *Mathematica* have a great power of dealing with quantifiers, once you can write a set in the second form above, you can do plenty of things and tricks that you would have thought to have nothing to do with programming before.
As we may write down the range of a function f in math this way: `{f(x) | x in Dom f}`, however, `f(x)` is not a "predicate", it's more closely to be thought as an object, so putting it into *Mathematica* programming might be difficult. What's lucky, we can write it using another way! That is`{ y | ∃x such that y=f(x)}`, where `∃x such that y=f(x)` is a propositional function of x. From now, you can use the build-in functions `Reduce` to get the all possible values of y.

For example, if you have a function y = x^3 + x + 6 in math,
and you want to find its range(w.r.t whole domain of f) or image of some proper set of its domain, try to use the the quantifier-family, ie `Reduce`, `ForAll` and `Exists`.

For example, here is the way to find the image of a set [1,15]

```
Reduce[Exists[x, 1 <= x <= 15, y == x^3 + x + 6], y, Reals]
Output: 8 <= y <= 3396
```

or find a range (w.r.t the whole domain of that function)

```
Reduce[Exists[x, y ==  (x^2+x)/(4-x)], y, Reals]
Output: y <= -9 - 4 Sqrt[5] || y >= 1/(-9 - 4 Sqrt[5])
```

After you become sophisticated with quantifiers, you are on a highly level of programming.

**Finding the multiples of 6 among 1~100.**

```
Reduce[Exists[x, x \[Element] Integers, y == 2 x] && 
  Exists[x, x \[Element] Integers, y == 3 x] && 
  1 <= y <= 100, y, Integers]
Output: y == 6 || y == 12 || y == 18 || y == 24 || y == 30 || y == 36 || y == 42 || y == 48 || y == 54 || y == 60 || y == 66 || y == 72 ||  y == 78 || y == 84 || y == 90 || y == 96
```

**Finding the distance between a fixed point and an arbitrary curve.**

This example is also very cool. Given a fixed point, take `(3,4)` for example and, an arbitrary curve defined by an equation, take `x^3 + y^3 + 2 x^2 y - 7 x y^2 + 8 x - 7 y + 46 == 0`. How to get the distance between the point and the graph?

First we need to insure that the point does not belong to the graph.

```
x^3 + y^3 + 2 x^2 y - 7 x y^2 + 8 x - 7 y + 46 == 0 /. {x -> 3, y -> 4}
Output: False
```

And we now try to get the set of *every* distance. This set collects all the distance from every points in the graph to the fixed point we picked.

```
Reduce[Exists[{x, y}, 
   x^3 + y^3 + 2 x^2 y - 7 x y^2 + 8 x - 7 y + 46 == 0 && 
   Sqrt[(x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2] == d], d, Reals]
Output: d >= Root[-3228313885871685449 + 3580719856462877084 #1^2 - 
        1341308868741195007 #1^4 + 229192171361605440 #1^6 - 
        21541588953050597 #1^8 + 1444606027764877 #1^10 - 
        58640497566169 #1^12 + 1358762455214 #1^14 - 17611698786 #1^16 + 
        102703185 #1^18 &, 6]

% //N
Output: d >= 1.33688
```

Perfect!

Another logic to do the same thing is:

```
N[Reduce[ForAll[{x, y}, 
  x^3 + y^3 + 2 x^2 y - 7 x y^2 + 8 x - 7 y + 46 == 0, 
  Sqrt[(x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2] >= dMin]], 10]
```

And we get: `dMin <= 1.336884157`

Have fun playing with quantifiers!

Comment: Also, `Reduce[{1 <= x <= 15, y == x^3 + x + 6}, y, {x}, Reals]`, `Reduce[
  y == (x^2 + x)/(4 - x), y, {x}, Reals]`