# How can I find the range of my function

Tags: functions

I am trying to find the range of `(3 Sin[x] - 3)/(2 Cos[x] + 10)`, I tried this,

```
Function[x, (3 Sin[x] - 3)/(2 Cos[x] + 10)]@ Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}]
```

*Mathematica* returned  `Interval[{-(3/4), 0}]`, but [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283%20Sin%5Bx%5D%20-%203%29/%282%20Cos%5Bx%5D%20%2b%2010%29%20range) returned `-5/8 <= y <= 0`. I'm sure Wolfram | Alpha is right What's wrong with my *Mathematica* code?

Comment: Related: [How to find the domain and range of a function with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/how-to-find-the-domain-and-range-of-a-function-with-mathematica)

Comment: -3/4 is less than -5/8, so both are right. Intervals are by no means guaranteed to be tight bounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your computation effectively yields the following:

```
(3 Interval[{-1, 1}] - 3)/(2 Interval[{-1, 1}] + 10)
(* Out: Interval[{-3/4, 0}] *)
```

The WolframAlpha code effectively computes the minimum and maximum of the function; it's more like so:

```
Minimize[(3 Sin[x] - 3)/(2 Cos[x] + 10), x] // Simplify
(* Out: {-5/8, {x -> 2*(Pi - ArcTan[3/2])}} *)
```

Comment: + See under possible issues : "Intervals are always assumed independent"

Answer (score 2):

I found `Reduce` is useful,

```
Reduce[y == (3 Sin[x] - 3)/(2 Cos[x] + 10), y, {x}, Reals]
% // Simplify

(* -(5/8) <= y <= 0 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new in M10 function [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange) to do this:

```
FunctionRange[(3 Sin[x]-3)/(2 Cos[x]+10), x, y] //Simplify
```

> -5/8 <= y <= 0