# Parallelization with two Processors: only half number of cores run

Tags: parallelization

I have a code which works really good in a parallelized way (with `ParallelTable`). I have a machine with 1 processor, 4 physical/8 logical cores, there 100% of the CPU is used for calculations:
[image]

I have another machine with 22 physical/44 logical cores. It also worked 100% there (i.e. it used 44 cores). Today I got another processor for that machine, so it has now 44/88 cores. But surprisingly, now it only uses 44 cores:
[image]

Of course, I started the 88 kernels manually:

[image]

For the reasons above, I don't think it's a problem with multithreading (as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115436/parallelization-works-but-does-not-use-all-cpu-power)), but that *Mathematica* does can not use two processors simultaneously. Unfortunately, I have not found any relevant information about this.

I will be very happy for every possible suggestion which leads to a solution (or workaround).

**Edit - more details on the system:**

The computer is a [HP Z840 Workstation with **2** Intel Xeon E5-2699v4 CPUs](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/workstations/product-detail.html?oid=11006449) with 2x22 physical/2x44 logical cores (see in the link, *Boost your HP Workstation performance when you need to by adding a second processor to your existing single-processor system*). Windows as well as several benchmarking programs detect and use the two Processors simultaneously.

I use Windows 10, and Mathematica 11.0.

**Edit2 (more details):**

When executing `ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID]`, it gives me a list from 1-88. When I execute `$ProcessorCount`, it gives me 22.

**Edit3 (`Parallelize` with different `Method`):**

Suggested in the discussion by rhermans, i tried different `Method`s, all from the documentation:

```
Parallelize[Map[Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &, Range[10]], Method -> "FinestGrained"]

Parallelize[Map[Labeled[Framed[#], $KernelID] &, Range[10]], Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]

Parallelize[Table[Labeled[Framed[i], $KernelID], {i, 12}], Method -> "EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 2]

Parallelize[Table[Labeled[Framed[i], $KernelID], {i, 18}], Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation" -> 5]

Parallelize[Table[Labeled[Framed[i], $KernelID], {i, 20}], Method -> Automatic]

Parallelize[Select[Range[4000, 5000], PrimeQ[2^# - 1] &], Method -> "FinestGrained"]
```

All of them have the same behaviour as stated above: only 44 out of 88 cores are running. Furthermore, the 44 cores stay at high (50-70%) CPU use, even after they finished the evaluation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62092/discussion-on-question-by-nicodean-parallelization-with-two-processors-only-hal).

Comment: What happens if you overwrite $ProcessorCount = 44?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of using only one of two processors has been solved in *Mathematica 11.1*.

[image: task manager screen shot]

The problem, that all cores stay active after finishing the parallel execution remains.

Comment: Can anyone speak to if this (or any dual processor) issues remain with Mathematica 12.3?

Comment: I used Mathematica 12 with a dual processor, and `ParallelTable` worked fine, i didnt do many other parallelizations. If you have concrete questions, let me know.

Comment: That's great.  Sounds like the "remaining active after finishing the parallel execution" issue has been resolved, then.