# Using dense matrix is faster than sparse matrix in LinearSolve

Tags: matrix, finite-element-method, sparse-arrays

I'm doing FEM with Mathematica and have to deal with [LinearSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) of a large matrix inside a Newton loop constantly. Hence I need to speed up the computation efficiency of LinearSolve. I'm aware of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10969/parallelization-problem-in-linearsolve-and-minimize).

Similarly, I test with the following code. First I tried with dense matrix:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
dim = 5000;
a = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {dim, dim}];
b = RandomReal[{1}, {dim}];
Table[SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> i];
  Print["Case=", i];
  Print[SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber"]];
  t = AbsoluteTime[];
  LinearSolve[a, b];
  time2 = AbsoluteTime[] - t;
  Print["t(", i, ")=", time2];
  Print["******"], {i, 4}];
```

The output is:

```
Case=1

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->1}}

t(1)=2.155357

******

Case=2

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->2}}

t(2)=1.279845

******

Case=3

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->3}}

t(3)=1.525075

******

Case=4

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->4}}

t(4)=1.246443

******
```

From the above test, it seems that the LinearSolve is automatically parallelized, which is good. My laptop has only 2 kennels hence no much improvement for 2,3, and 4 threads. Then I run it again with sparse matrix:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
dim = 5000;
a = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {dim, dim}];
b = RandomReal[{1}, {dim}];
sa = SparseArray[a];
sb = SparseArray[b];
Table[SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> i];
  Print["Case=", i];
  Print[SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber"]];
  t = AbsoluteTime[];
  LinearSolve[sa, sb];
  time2 = AbsoluteTime[] - t;
  Print["t(", i, ")=", time2];
  Print["******"], {i, 4}];
```

However, it seems that LinearSolve needs much more time to deal with sparse matrix then with dense matrix.

```
Case=1

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->1}}

t(1)=11.346750

******

Case=2

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->2}}

t(2)=5.508803

******

Case=3

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->3}}

t(3)=5.551608

******

Case=4

{ParallelOptions->{MKLThreadNumber->4}}

t(4)=5.518430

******
```

This seems a little bit weird to me since I have experienced the improved efficiency by converting a dense matrix into sparse matrix in Matlab. Can anyone explain this? Is there any other way to speed up LinearSolve?

Comment: Using a sparse array is effective when the array is actually sparse. You are converting a dense array into a sparse array that has a sparsity of 0, so I'm not surprised that sparse methods are slower.

Comment: If sparse matrix methods were faster than methods for dense matrices, when working with dense matrices, then the dense methods would disappear. Voting to close on grounds that there is no clear reason to expect behavior any different from what was observed.

Comment: As already noted, trying to use sparse methods on a demonstrably dense matrix is a fool's errand. You had chosen an especially poor example to present your premise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's not having the necessary understanding of the  Mathematica objects he is working with.

Comment: With only 2 kennels there is an upper bound how many dogs you can have running efficiently in parallell.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot benefit from `SparseArray` if your matrix is not sparse! The data structure storing a `SparseArray` needs a certain amount of overhead which only pays off if your matrix is really, really sparse (density below a permille or so). Moreover, whenever you find yourself *converting* a large matrix to a sparse matrix *you have actually done something wrong*. `SparseArray`s have to be constructed in a sparse way by special constructor functions (the constructor functions are called `SparseArray` in Mathematica and `sparse` in MATLAB).

But admittedly, a point that is bugging me is that Mathematica uses UMFPACK for factorizations  of `SparseArrays` (as backend of `LinearSolve`). While UMFPACK is quite robust, it is rather slow, *extremely* memory hungry, and not parallelized. However, we have the alternative to use the mostly undocumented option `Method->"Pardiso"` in `LinearSolve` which uses the Intel MKL Pardiso solver; and Pardiso is (partially) parallelized (back substitution is hardly parallelizable).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Do u imply that linearsolve is not parallelized by saying "While UMFPACK is quite robust, its is rather slow, extremely memory hungry and it is not parallelized"?

Comment: The reason I said that is that I set SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> 1] and SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> 16], respectively. However, there is little difference of computing time.

Comment: Yes, that's what I say. Still, `LinearSolve` will perform magnitudes better for `SparseArrays` arising in FEM than for the according densified matrices.

Comment: I think you may assume that the default parameters `"ParallelOptions"` are already optimized for your system.

Comment: If this is the case, how the computing time is decreased from 2.155357 to 1.279845 when changing MKLThreadNumber from 1 to 2?@Henrik Schumacher

Comment: Ah, interesting. Seemingly UMFPACK still profits from parallelization. Thinking of it: UMFPACK might call BLAS or SparseBLAS routines and those _are_ parallelized.