# Why does iterating Prime in reverse order require much more time?

Tags: performance-tuning, implementation-details, number-theory, prime-numbers

Say I would like to display the $10$ greatest primes that are less than $10^5$. I could do the following:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 M = 10^5; m = PrimePi[M];
 prms = Prime[#] & /@ Range[1, m];
 prms[[#]] & /@ Range[-1, -10, -1]
 ]
```

And the result comes out :

```
{0.0156250, {99991, 99989, 99971, 99961, 99929, 99923, 99907, 99901, 99881, 99877}}
```

But if I tried to do in in reverse,

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 M = 10^5; m = PrimePi[M];
 prms = Prime[#] & /@ Range[m, 1, -1];
 prms[[#]] & /@ Range[1, 10]
 ]
```

the process takes a whole lot longer:

```
{0.6250000, {99991, 99989, 99971, 99961, 99929, 99923, 99907, 99901, 
  99881, 99877}}
```

Using the second method, I can't even increase `M` to $10^6$, as the program takes extremely long to execute. Can anybody offer some insight into this ? $\;$ Am I essentially not doing the same thing in both cases ?

Comment: Probably `Prime[n]` makes use of results for `Prime[m], m < n`, but it caches only a limited number of results.  But this is just a guess and you have surely though of it already.

Comment: So with a clear memory, Prime[n] runs in O(n) time..

Comment: `Prime` and `PrimePi` are `Listable`, they are automatically mapped over a list, thus you can simply write e.g. `Prime @ Range @ m` instead of `Prime[#] & /@ Range[1, m]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given a large `n`, to find `k` largest primes below `n` (as well as above)  the best approach uses [`NextPrime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NextPrime.html?q=NextPrime&lang=en) (it has been added to `Mathematica 6`) :

> NextPrime[n] gives the next prime above n.
>
> NextPrime[n,k]  gives the k-th prime above n. If k is negative it gives k-th largest prime below n.

`k` need not be a single number but it may be a list of integers, so if we are looking for `k` consecutive primes we can take advanted of `Range`, e.g. :

```
NextPrime[ 100000, Range[-10, -1]]
```

> ```
> {99877, 99881, 99901, 99907, 99923, 99929, 99961, 99971, 99989, 99991}
> ```

The issue with `Prime` and `PrimePi` is that they are internally related however their documentation pages are not very informative.  There are certain limitations of these functions (look at a related question :  [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime) ). 
`Prime` calls `PrimePi` (e.g. this [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime#comment9022_3327) by  Oleksandr R.) if `Prime[n] < 25 10^13`. One can guess what is going on from [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) where it says:

> `Prime` and `PrimePi` use sparse caching and sieving.
>       For large $n$, the Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko algorithm for `PrimePi` is used, 
>       based on asymptotic estimates of the density of primes, and is inverted to give `Prime`.

So if one has found a large prime, generically the system definitely has found some close primes too (sparse **caching** and **sieving**) and of course internal algorithms are not symmetric around a large $n$, i.e. finding closest $k$ primes below and above  $n$ is not symmetric (basically it is implied by decreasing density of primes (globally) but directly it is determined by the Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko method ). For more information take a look at this crucial reference :  [Computing $ \pi(x)$: the Meissel-Lehmer method](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777285-5/home.html). If you want to find really large primes a fast algorithm should use `PrimeQ` however it is known to be correct only for $n < 10^{16}$. Another algorithm which is correct for all natural `n` is much slower, one can find it in `PrimalityProving` package .

Comment: this helps a lot, thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Addendum**

If you just want the greatest 10 primes less than M, you can start from `Prime[PrimePi[M]-9]`. By doing so, you gain a speed increase of 2 orders of magnitude when `M = 100000`.

```
M = 100000;
m = PrimePi[M]
AbsoluteTiming[Table[Prime[k], {k, m - 9, m}]]
```

> 9592
>   {0.000171, {99877, 99881, 99901, 99907, 99923, 99929, 99961, 99971, 99989, 99991}}

Now backwards (after closing and re-opening *Mathematica* and defining `M` and `m`.).
This is 10 x slower than the above, but still faster than starting from `Prime[1]`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[Prime[k], {k, m, m - 9, -1}]]
```

> {0.001467, {99991, 99989, 99971, 99961, 99929, 99923, 99907, 99901, 99881, 99877}}

One might expect that `NextPrime` would provide an advantage.  We restart *Mathematica* and find out that it is only marginally better than our last attempt.

```
AbsoluteTiming[NestList[NextPrime, Prime[m - 9], 9]]
```

> {0.001193, {99877, 99881, 99901, 99907, 99923, 99929, 99961, 99971, 99989, 99991}}

---

**My Earlier answers about the order of the iterator**.

I conducted the following tests starting at `Prime[1]`. Even though this is a very inefficient approach, the results will be easier to compare to those of the OP.

We want to rule out `Range` so we take it out of the timing. Likewise, we set `M` and `m` first, before conducting the timing.

```
M = 100000;
m = PrimePi[M];
r1 = Range[1, m];
r2 = Range[m, 1, -1];
```

**Backwards request of primes much slower than forwards request** (the original observation)

```
r1 == Reverse[r2]
AbsoluteTiming[prms = Prime[#] & /@ r1;]
AbsoluteTiming[prms = Prime[#] & /@ r2;]
```

> True
>   {0.009920, Null}
>   {0.354147, Null}

Puzzling. Yet absolutely consistent with what you observed.

It appears that `r1` may be stored in a form that can be processed more quickly  than `r2`.

---

**Half backwards, Half forwards**: Only half as bad as all backwards.

Let's look a little deeper.

`r3` is the sub-list of odd numbers, followed by the even numbers.

`r5` is like `r3` but the odd numbers were reversed.

```
r3 = Transpose[Partition[r1, 2]] // Flatten;
r4 = Transpose[Partition[r1, 2]];
r5 = Join[Reverse[r4[[1]]], r4[[2]]];
```

Let's time the processing of r3 and r5:

```
AbsoluteTiming[prms = Prime[#] & /@ r3;]
AbsoluteTiming[prms = Prime[#] & /@ r5;]
```

> {0.012765, Null}
>   {0.205590, Null}

Half the numbers in r5 were ordered from larger to smaller.
The delay was about 1/2 the delay we saw when all numbers were ordered from larger to smaller.

Provisional conclusion:  *Mathematica* "counts" primes forwards faster than backwards(?)

---

**Random Ordering**

```
r6 = RandomSample[r1, 9592];
AbsoluteTiming[prms = Prime[#] & /@ r6;]
```

> {0.190770, Null}

The (pseudo)random ordering of numbers runs as fast as the backwards-forwards list!

---

**Lingering Question**: Why should a random ordering of numbers be faster to process than a "backwards request" for primes?   I would have guessed that the random case would be at least as slow, or slower than the backward case.

P.S. @Szabolcs Please look at the results above and see whether they are consistent with your hunch. (I'm uncertain whether they are.)  Perhaps *Mathematica* only stores the results of the final outcome.  In this case the backwards request would receive no benefits.

---

**Szabolcs' suggestion**

Here are some orderings recommended by Szabolcs. Notice how the orderings increasingly move toward canonical ordering from least to greatest.

```
Table[{k, First@Timing[
 Prime /@ Flatten@Reverse@Partition[Range[1, 20], k]]}, {k, 1, 10}];
Table[{k, Prime /@ Flatten@Reverse@Partition[Range[1, 20], k]}, {k, 1,10}]
```

[image: ordering]

And their respective timings:

```
Table[{k, First@Timing[Prime /@ Flatten@Reverse@Partition[Range[1, 20000], k];]}, {k, 1,10}]
```

> {{1, 2.540567}, {2, 1.275608}, {3, 0.858899}, {4, 0.647391}, {5, 
>     0.517372}, {6, 0.431639}, 
>       {7, 0.370851}, {8, 0.325734}, {9, 0.291674}, {10, 0.262256}}

Here's the canonical ordering:

```
First@Timing[Prime /@ Flatten@Partition[Range[1, 20000], 1];]
```

> 0.011894

Comment: r1 and r2 I think you meant..

Comment: Yes, thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: This kind of ordering is an interesting experiment too: `Table[
 {k, First@
   Timing[Prime /@ Flatten@Reverse@Partition[Range[1, 20000], k];]},
 {k, 1, 10}
 ]`

Comment: Yes! Very nice. I'm comparing that output to `First@Timing[Prime /@ Flatten@Partition[Range[1, 20000], 1];]`

Comment: One would expect the random ordering to be the slowest, very interesting..