# How does Mathematica calculate the nth prime?

Tags: implementation-details, number-theory, prime-numbers

When I enter `Prime[2000000000000]`, the two-trillionth prime, *Mathematica* gives `61427839512211` for the answer after several minutes of calculation.

I wonder how it calculates to get this number. Apparently, it does not pull that number out from a list, since it spends several minutes to get the answer.

Comment: Related: [What is so special about Prime?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime)  Another possibly interesting [Why does iterating Prime in reverse order require much more time?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15799/why-does-iterating-prime-in-reverse-order-require-much-more-time)

Answer (score 6):

From [Some Notes On Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#12788):

> `Prime` and `PrimePi` use sparse caching and sieving. For large $n$, the [Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1985-0777285-5) for `PrimePi` is used, based on asymptotic estimates of the density of primes, and is inverted to give `Prime`.

Comment: I believe community wiki abuse is mentioned as a scientific perversion somewhere in the Marquis de Sade complete works.

Comment: @bel, I would have left it as a comment, but it was too damn long. :P