# Number of primes p less than or equal to X satisfying a congruence relation

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm looking for a code that finds the number of primes p less than or equal to X satisfying p is congruent to 1 (mod 4) and another code that finds the number of primes p less than or equal to X satisfying p is congruent to 3 (mod 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function that takes in a range and a criterion function.

```
fPrime[X_?NumericQ, f_Function] := {Length@#, #} &@
  Table[If[f@Prime[i], Prime[i], Nothing], {i, PrimePi[X]}]
```

**Usage**

```
fPrime[100, Mod[#, 4] == 1 &]
```

> {11, {5, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 53, 61, 73, 89, 97}}

```
fPrime[100, Mod[#, 4] == 3 &]
```

> {13, {3, 7, 11, 19, 23, 31, 43, 47, 59, 67, 71, 79, 83}}

Comment: I’m trying to find the number of primes in a large interval. It seems like what you’re providing is going to give me a set of primes and not the count.

Comment: It is providing you with both and you can choose to drop what you don't need.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[Range[100],And[PrimeQ[#],Mod[#,4]==1]&]
(* {5,13,17,29,37,41,53,61,73,89,97} *)

Select[Range[100],And[PrimeQ[#],Mod[#,4]==3]&]
(* {3,7,11,19,23,31,43,47,59,67,71,79,83} *)
```

Comment: One can observe that `PrimePi4m1[x]+PrimePi4m3[x]+1==PrimePi[x]`. This is the first step to make it more efficient.  Another step would be harnessing `PrimePi` in a more extended way, something like it was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/generate-primepower-counting-function/37400#37400).

Comment: Thank you. This code is really just a translation of an English sentence into Mathematica (more or less). There is certainly room for improvement if efficiency is a concern.

Comment: I’m not sure how to make this code work since it’s giving me the primes and not the number of primes.

Comment: You can apply Length to the result.