# `PrimeNu` counting function

Tags: function-construction, number-theory, prime-numbers

Building on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38467/prime-factor-counting-function), what is the most efficient counting function for ***distinct*** prime factors? It would obviously be more efficient if `Prime` and `PrimePi` were used instead of `PrimeNu`, as *ybeltukov* and *Coolwater* used in their brilliant solutions to the `PrimeOmega` counting function question. I was wondering whether there was any way to do something similar in this instance?

The best I have so far is a (very) minor modification of *ubpdqn's* reply to my previous question:

```
cnt[k_, n_] := Last@Reap[Sow[1, PrimeNu@#] & /@ Range[n], k, Total@#2 &]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No brilliance here, but on my machine the following function is 8 or 9 times faster than`cnt[k,n]`.

```
DistinctPrimes[k_, n_] :=
   Block[{r=Range[n]}, Length[Pick[r, Map[Length,FactorInteger[r]], k]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are making this far more complicated than it needs to be.  Look at [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Count.html).  [KennyColnago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3246/kennycolnago) is wise to use listability, and to my surprise his use of `FactorInteger` is faster than `PrimeNu` at least in version 7.  Here are two functions to compare:

```
f1[k_, n_] := Count[PrimeNu @ Range @ n, k]
f2[k_, n_] := Count[Length /@ FactorInteger @ Range @ n, k]
```

In version 7:

```
f1[6, 150000] // Timing
f2[6, 150000] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.544, 64}
>
> {0.281, 64}
> ```

Comment: It is actually not the speed I am after (though it would be nice) - my goal is to find dpf for very large numbers.

Comment: @martin Sorry, I missed that.  How large is "very large" and you willing to wait a long time for very large numbers?

Comment: Somewhere in the range 10^40 would be nice -  but as large as poss, really :) Don't mind waiting, but only running on Windows 32-bit platform.

Comment: @martin Oh dear; this method will never scale to that degree.  I hope someone with greater knowledge has a more clever approach for you.

Comment: Just to confirm:`FactorInteger` is faster than `PrimeNu` in version 9 as well, which makes no sense to me...