# What are the limits of the Prime-functions?

Tags: implementation-details, prime-numbers

Will `Prime` and `PrimePi` test up to `3 * 10^12`? Where can I find the limits for these funtions? Also, what are the limits for `PrimeOmega` and `PrimeNu`? More generally, is there any documentation that gives limits for all of *Mathematica's* functions?

Comment: Try [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheLimitsOfMathematica.html)

Comment: I can't find the answer there unfortunately

Comment: The maximum of Prime has been discussed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime/3365#3365

Comment: Ilian Gachevski mentions [over at wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/119394;jsessionid=A9CE6039CBD0F70583B95795A374DBF3.wlp1?p_p_auth=zmJhE2IX) that `PrimeQ` is valid up to $2^{64}$

Comment: Test in PrimalityProving is correct for all natural numbers but is much slower.