# Internals of Prime function

Tags: implementation-details, prime-numbers

Does anyone knows how exactly `Prime` works ?

For example how `Prime[1000000000]` is calculated ?

The only information I found was some inequalities in [Wolfram's Function site](http://functions.wolfram.com/).

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is so special about Prime?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3327/121).  [Implementation notes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) state only: "`Prime` and `PrimePi` use sparse caching and sieving. For large *n*, the Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko algorithm for `PrimePi` is used, based on asymptotic estimates of the density of primes, and is inverted to give `Prime`."

Comment: What you ask here in principle you can find in the links provided by Mr.Wizard. I asked there a bit more general question, however the answers provided were not fully explanatory. This is the case here as well, since you'll have to study the Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko paper which is crucial for understanding how `PrimePi` works. Then `Prime` could be implemented e.g. this way: `prime[z_Integer] /; z >= 1 := 
 x /. First @
   Solve[PrimePi[x] == z && PrimePi[x - 1] == z - 1, x, Integers]`