# Limits of PrimeNu

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

Is there any way to find distinct prime factors for very large numbers using `Prime` and/or `PrimePi` that exceeds the capabilities/limits of `PrimeNu`?

Comment: No, in general it's impossible. I gave a comment to one of your similar recent questions and that should be clear enough from that comment. Once more I have to put this link: [What is so special about Prime?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime). `PrimeNu` can evaluate its value for e.g. `50!` while neither `Prime` nor `PrimePi` cannot. Seems like you don't read comments to your questions. Is it clear enough ?

Comment: OK many thanks - I did read previous comments, but was clearly not understanding things correctly.