# Approximation to the prime counting function

Tags: special-functions, number-theory, approximation, prime-numbers

Is there a function similar to [`PrimePi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimePi.html) that gives approximate value for large numbers?

In particular, I need a reasonably good approximation for $\pi(x)$, where $x\approx10^{1000}$.

More or less a function that gives $\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\ln t}$ or better.

Edit: I settled for the definite integral approximation but if someone knows of a built-in function that performs better, I'm definitely interested.

Comment: `LogIntegral` is this integral. Try this: `Show[{Plot[LogIntegral[x], {x, 1, 2000}], 
  ListPlot[Table[PrimePi[n], {n, 1, 2000}]]}]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best analytic built-in approximation is the [Riemann Prime Counting Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html); it is implemented in *Mathematica* as [`RiemannR`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiemannR.html?q=RiemannR).  So far we know exact values of $\pi$ prime counting function for  `n < 10^25`, however in *Mathematica* its counterpart `PrimePi[n]` can be computed exactly to much lower values i.e. up to `25 10^13 -1`, see e.g. [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime) for more details.

```
RiemannR[10^1000] // N
```

> ```
> 4.344832576401197453*10^996
> ```

See e.g. [Prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), it claims that the best estimator is $
\operatorname{R}(x) - \frac1{\ln x} + \frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x}$

let's define it as `APi`:

```
APi[x_] := RiemannR[x] - 1/Log[x] + 1/Pi ArcTan[ Pi/Log[x]]
```

it provides the same approximation as `RiemannR`, at least `IntegerPart` does,
 in fact

```
Grid[ Table[ IntegerPart @ { 5 10^k, RiemannR[5 10^k] - PrimePi[5 10^k], 
                             APi[5 10^k] - PrimePi[5 10^k]}, {k, 3, 13}],
      Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

We can realize how good `RiemanR`  is plotting related errors of interesting approximations where we know exact values of the prime counting function (see e.g. "Mathematica in Action" by Stan Wagon):

```
Plot[{ LogIntegral[x] - PrimePi[x], RiemannR[x] - PrimePi[x], 
        x/(Log[x] - 1) - PrimePi[x]},  {x, 2, 3 10^5}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
      Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Darker @ Green}, 
                                  {Thick, Darker @ Cyan}}, 
      PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Bottom}], 
      ImageSize -> 800, AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{ LogIntegral[x] - PrimePi[x], RiemannR[x] - PrimePi[x], 
       x/(Log[x] - 1) - PrimePi[x]}, {x, 10^6, 10^7}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
       Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Darker @ Green}, 
                                    {Thick, Darker @ Cyan}}, 
       PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Bottom}], 
       Axes -> {True, False}, AxesStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could accept both replies as the answer; however, I'm obliged to accept Karsten's correct reply because it was posted first. However, let me stress that I thoroughly enjoyed reading your reply and, particularly, the content of the links you provided.

Comment: @user2943324 You can accept whatever you want however you don't have to choose the first answer, moreover accepting too quickly you discourage others (including me) to post another answers possibly better. As far as I can say I could elaborate   my answer improving it,  even though so far I've provided more details than the other answer.

Comment: Agreed. It seems that I am too quick to mark a reply as accepted. You have to forgive me. I don't frequent these forums often enough and when I do, it seems, I inadvertently get too excited.

Answer (score 6):

[`RiemannR`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiemannR.html?q=RiemannR) seems to be a better choice than [`LogIntegral`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogIntegral.html?q=LogIntegral) based on this plot:

```
Plot[{PrimePi[n], LogIntegral[n], RiemannR[n]}, {n, 1, 5000}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Red}]
```

> [image: primePiPlot]

```
RiemannR[1.*10^1000]
```

> ```
> 4.344832576401197453*10^996
> ```

Comment: That gets my vote (as does the other `RiemannR` response). I'll note it is somewhat slower to compute, although still fast enough for whatever purposes.