# Prime power list

Tags: prime-numbers

## Update

Is there any better way of generating the nth prime power?

Chip Hurst gave a great solution for a list below, so

```
PrimePowersUpTo[x_] := Union @@ Table[Prime[Range[PrimePi[x^(1/n)]]]^n, {n, Log2[x]}]
pp=PrimePowersUpTo[10^7];
pp[[n]]
```

would work, but I was wondering whether there was a more direct way?

## Original question

I am trying to get a list of prime powers, but I can only seem to get one that goesx to 10^7.

```
xmax = 10000000;
rr = DeleteCases[Table[If[PrimePowerQ[n] == True, n, 0], {n, 1, xmax}], 0];
```

or

```
Select[Range[10], PrimePowerQ]
```

I tried using Artes' idea of taking log base prime as per [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/generate-primepower-counting-function), but didn't get very far.

Is there any way I can go to 10^12?

Comment: `PrimePi[10^12]` is a very large number ...

Comment: @belisarius yes, I was rather hoping I could go that high ...

Comment: You can estimate reasonably `PrimePi` with `RiemannR` even if _Mathematica_ implementation doesn't help, e.g.  `RiemannR[10^12] // N` yields `3.76079*10^10`. See also  [Approximation to the prime counting function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60053/approximation-to-the-prime-counting-function/60056#60056).

Comment: @Artes I'm not sure I follow - how would this help me find the nth prime power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my way of finding the nth prime power. I do a binary search. Unfortunately it's slow for large inputs.

```
lower[_] = 2;
upper[x_] := Prime[x]

PrimePower[n_] := Module[{lo = lower[n], hi = upper[n], mid, pp},
    mid = Quotient[lo + hi, 2];

    While[lo < mid < hi && (pp = PrimePowerPi[mid]) != n,
        If[pp > n,
            hi = mid,
            lo = mid
        ];
        mid = Quotient[lo + hi, 2];
    ];

    PreviousPrimePower[mid]
]

PreviousPrimePower[x_] := Max[Table[NextPrime[x^(1/n), -1]^n, {n, Log2[x]}]]
```

Examples:

```
PrimePowerPi[10^7]
```

> ```
> 665134
> ```

```
PrimePower[665134]
```

> ```
> 9999991
> ```

```
PrimePowerPi[10^12]
```

> ```
> 37607992088
> ```

```
PrimePower[37607992088]
```

> ```
> 999999999989
> ```

---

From Daniel Lichtblau:

Feel free to use this variant (divides more finely).

```
PrimePowerb[n_] := Module[
  {lo = lower[n], hi = upper[n], mid, ppmid, pphi, pplo}, 
  mid = Round[.95*hi];
  ppmid = PrimePowerPi[mid];
  pplo = 1;
  pphi = PrimePowerPi[hi];
  While[lo < mid < hi && ppmid != n,
   If[ppmid > n,
    hi = mid;
    pphi = ppmid;
    mid = mid + Round[(lo - mid)*(n - ppmid)/(pplo - ppmid)];
    ,
    lo = mid;
    pplo = ppmid;
    mid = mid + Round[(hi - mid)*(n - ppmid)/(pphi - ppmid)];
    ];
   If[mid == lo, mid++];
   If[mid == hi, mid--];
   ppmid = PrimePowerPi[mid];
   ];
  PreviousPrimePower[mid]]
```

Comment: thank you! this works really well :)

Comment: Feel free to use this variant (divides more finely). `PrimePowerb[n_] := Module[
  {lo = lower[n], hi = upper[n], mid, ppmid, pphi, pplo}, 
  mid = Round[.95*hi];
  ppmid = PrimePowerPi[mid];
  pplo = 1;
  pphi = PrimePowerPi[hi];
  While[lo < mid < hi && ppmid != n,
   If[ppmid > n,
    hi = mid;
    pphi = ppmid;
    mid = mid + Round[(lo - mid)*(n - ppmid)/(pplo - ppmid)];
    ,
    lo = mid;
    pplo = ppmid;
    mid = mid + Round[(hi - mid)*(n - ppmid)/(pphi - ppmid)];
    ];
   If[mid == lo, mid++];
   If[mid == hi, mid--];
   ppmid = PrimePowerPi[mid];
   ];
  PreviousPrimePower[mid]]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau just seen thas - thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
PrimePowersUpTo[x_] := Union @@ Table[Prime[Range[PrimePi[x^(1/n)]]]^n, {n, Log2[x]}]

PrimePowersUpTo[10^7] // Length
```

> ```
> 665134
> ```

Now about getting the first 10^12 prime powers. You would want to get them in batches (segmented sieve) because there are about 38 billion of them:

```
PrimePowerPi[x_] := Sum[PrimePi[x^(1/n)], {n, Log2[x]}]

PrimePowerPi[10^12]
```

> ```
> 37607992088
> ```

Comment: is there any way of generating the `n`th prime power?

Comment: You might generate the nth prime and then subtract your way down to account for the relatively fewer powers that also near that value. Possibly you can use a tighter estimate since you have ways to approximate how many of those there are, but then you also have to count carefully so as not to include powers that are too large.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I don't suppose you could elaborate in an answer, could you?