# The inverse function of "Prime"

Tags: prime-numbers

Consider p such that `PrimeQ[p] == True`. How do I compute n such that `Prime[n] == p`?

In other words, what is the inverse function of "Prime"?

EDIT:

As a concrete example, consider `p` to be the first prime that factorizes rsa-768,

```
p = rsa768a = 33478071698956898786044169848212690817704794983713768568912431388982883793878002287614711652531743087737814467999489
```

`PrimeQ[rsa768a]` is True; I want to know its n.

Trying Jason's suggestion, `InverseFunction[Prime][rsa768a]`, does not return the expected result (for a small prime it does). Trying LLlAMnYP suggestion, `PrimePi[rsa768a]` returns

> PrimePi::largp: Argument ... in PrimePi[...] is too large for this implementation. >>

Comment: `InverseFunction[Prime]`

Comment: @JasonB Cheeky :-P and cruel. `PrimePi` is much faster.

Comment: I don't understand how it's cheeky or cruel, it's direct and does what is intended, right?

Comment: It's *so* direct, it's almost mocking the OP, but I like, how it shows off Mathematica's capability to do the thinking for you. But on a more serious note, I can't imagine when it would be preferable to `PrimePi`.

Comment: Because `PrimePi` will take non-prime numbers and give an answer

Comment: `primePi[x_?PrimeQ]:=PrimePi[x]`

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, they answered to the question I posed, only not for any prime p. I edited by question to include the case I was testing.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão, neither of these would work for a number that large apparently

Comment: You can attempt to use `NextPrime[#, -1]&` but good luck waiting for that computation to end in this universe. There's a reason, that these things are used for encryption, y'know :-)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão  This question [What is so special about Prime?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime) explicitly states this problem. `Prime` has an extensible domain, however you can't extend it up to `rsa768a` unless you have an enormous amount of RAM, but it is unlikely realizable.

Comment: [This page](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/893767/210969) links to quite a few algorithms you could code yourself for the prime counting function, but I don't see any of them listed as being applicable to a number over $10^{115}$

Comment: @JasonB, thanks. Another option is to solve `n Log[n] == p` (or other approximation of $p_n$) for n.

Comment: If you need a good approximation for `PrimePi` see e.g. [Approximation to the prime counting function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60053/approximation-to-the-prime-counting-function/60056#60056).

Comment: Indeed, you can't really expect to get an exact value of `n` in any sensible time for such large primes (well, maybe doing some original research in quantum computation might help), but maybe you can live with the fact `RiemannR` is good for an approximation.