# Is this a reliable method for getting a list of very large primes?

Tags: performance-tuning, prime-numbers

As noted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime), both `PrimePi` and `Prime` are documented as having their limits somwhere around $10^{15}.$ `PrimeQ` and `NextPrime` on the other hand don't seem to be so restricted. Is the following a reliable way of getting around that for short intervals of primes at greater heights?

```
pGAPS[r1_, r2_] := 
  If[r1 < 3, 
    "start range must be > 2", 
    With[{bb = Split @ PrimeQ @ Range[r1, r2]}, 
      With[{cc = If[bb[[1, 1]] == False, bb[[;; ;; 2]], bb[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]},
        Most @ Rest @ (Length @ #& /@ cc + 1)]]]

With[{a = 10^20, b = 10^20 + 10^4}, NextPrime[a] + Accumulate @ pGAPS[a, b]]
```

If so, Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Related? ([3327](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime))

Comment: @blochwave - thanks for link - have incorporated into question now :)

Comment: Also note this discussion [over on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/114911)

Comment: @blachwave - thanks, hadn't seen that one - will give it a read

Comment: Why not just `With[{a = #1, b = #2}, 
  Rest@NestWhileList[NextPrime, NextPrime[a], # <= b &]] &` - simpler and as fast...

Comment: @ciao nice :) thanks - definitely simpler !