# How Prime[n] is implemented and why is that bounded?

Tags: number-theory, implementation-details, prime-numbers

How is `Prime[n]` implemented in Mathematica? I have just observed that calculating large primes is quite fast (but not in `O(1)` time).

```
In[9]:= Prime[10^11]                                                       
Out[9]= 2760727302517 //not instant
In[10]:= Prime[10^11]                                                      
Out[10]= 2760727302517 //instant
In[11]:= Prime[10^12]                                                      
Out[11]= 29996224275833 //not instant, seems to be k times longer than 10^11
```

I have also observed that it uses `~O(1)` memory so things like Atkin sieve are not used there and that results are stored in memory because each next query returns result instantly.

In [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prime.html) there are not details about that.

From the other hand it can't be predefined (it is not O(1)) but after putting:

```
In[13]:= Prime[10^20]                                                      

Prime::largp: Argument 100000000000000000000 in 
    Prime[100000000000000000000] is too large for this implementation.

Out[13]= Prime[100000000000000000000]
```

Why is this bound if that implementation has not predefined primes?

Comment: From [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#31613): "`Prime` and `PrimePi` use sparse caching and sieving. For large $n$, the Lagarias–Miller–Odlyzko algorithm for `PrimePi` is used, based on asymptotic estimates of the density of primes, and is inverted to give `Prime`."

Comment: Interesting source @MarcoB

Comment: Basically this question has been asked  in  [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime).  There is an arbitrary cut-off for `PrimePi` and then "inverting" it we get a bound for `Prime`.