# Determining occurrence of a sequence of numbers in the first 50,000 primes

Tags: pattern-matching, prime-numbers, digit-sequences

I have to determine how many of the first 50,000 prime numbers (digits) contain the sequence 5, 4, 3, in that order. The numbers don't have to necessarily be consecutive. For example, 566453 is a prime number that would count. All I've been able to do is determine the first 50,000 prime numbers.

Answer (score 13):

```
out = Select[MatchQ[IntegerDigits[#], {___, 5, ___, 4, ___, 3, ___}] &]@
   Prime[Range[50000]];

Length@out
```

> 1588

```
Short@out
```

> {1543, 2543, 5413, 5431, 5437, 5443, 5483, 5743, 5843, 8543, <<1568>>, 599243, 599413, 599843, 601543, 602543, 605413, 605443, 605543, 610543, 611543}

If you need just the count:

```
count = Count[{___, 5, ___, 4, ___, 3, ___}]@*IntegerDigits@*Prime@*Range;
count @ 50000
```

> 1588

Answer (score 11):

`Prime`  and `IntegerDigits` are `Listable`, `___` (i.e. `BlankNullSequence`) is a pattern object that can stand for any sequence of zero or more expressions.

This is a nice approach and quite fast:

```
Length @ Cases[ IntegerDigits @ Prime @ Range @ 50000,
                          {___, 5, ___, 4, ___, 3, ___}]
```

> ```
> 1588
> ```

**Remarks**

This metod and kglr's operator approach based on `Count` seem to be equally efficient. However a reliable estimation of efficiency in case of large sets of primes should be carefully compared (with refreshing the kernels) since the algorithms behind `Prime` use sparse caching and sieving, to gain an insight I recommend to think over this question [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime).  Instead of `Length` one might exploit `CountDistinct` in case of duplicates presence.

Answer (score 8):

This should be speedier...

```
Pick[p = Prime@Range@5*^4, StringMatchQ[IntegerString[p], "*5*4*3*"]]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Prime[Range[50000]] // Short
IntegerDigits /@ % // Short
Flatten[SequenceCases[#, {___, 5, ___, 4, ___, 3, ___}] & /@ %, 1] // Length

(* 1588 *)
```

If you want the actual primes, replace the last line by

```
FromDigits /@ Flatten[SequenceCases[#, {___, 5, ___, 4, ___, 3, ___}] & /@ %, 1]
(* {1543, 2543, 5413, 5431, 5437, 5443, 5483, 5743, 5843, ..., 602543, 605413, 605443, 605543, 610543, 611543} *)
```