# Faster Prime[n] for large n, and for n larger than 10^12

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there a faster implementation of Prime[] available somewhere, already implemented by someone? (Maybe as a compiled routine?)

The default function in Mathematica is slow for large values, and does not work for very large values (greater than 10^12). I need a faster version that also works on very large values.

I'm aware that there are fast implementations of prime counting function ([e.g. kimwalisch, c++](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount)) that can be then used to estimate and zero in Prime[n] for very large n. But, I'm wondering if this problem was already efficiently solved for Mathematica in the form of a new prime[n] routine?

Comment: This question is related to [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime) where one can find further details (`Prime` is based on implementation of `PrimePi`), however  since the version 12.1 these functions have been updated with possible choice of method. I should have update my question too since limits of the functions have changed.

Comment: Do you need exact answers or are approximations enough? `Solve[LogIntegral[x] == 10^12, x]` has a fractional error of about $10^{-7}$ compared to the exact answer `Prime[10^12]`.

Comment: @Roman Exact answer.