# Largest n in Prime[n]

Tags: prime-numbers, system-limitations

What is the largest integer $n$ that the function `Prime[n]` can take?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is so special about Prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/what-is-so-special-about-prime). The documentation of [`Prime::largp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Prime/largp.html) still reports around $2^{42}$ as a potential limit, but the exact number can be implementation-dependent.

Comment: Haha, this made me laugh. My mac pooped out somewhere around 10^17. When I tried 10^18 my kernel crashed and I got [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDgRr.png)

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks a bunch!